# How to get subscription expiry date in android?

Tags: android, android-parser, android-json

I am trying to get subscription expiry date using purchase status API (https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/packageName/subscriptions/subscriptionId/purchases/token) but getting below response.May I know what is the correct way to achieve my objective?

```
"error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
```

Is anybody know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it is Android-JSON Parsing case

Comment: What you want to do with JSON??

Comment: i wanted to get response like below `{
  "kind": "androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase",
  "initiationTimestampMsec": long,
  "validUntilTimestampMsec": long,
  "autoRenewing": boolean
}`  using https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/packageName/subscriptions/subscriptionId/purchases/token. But i'm getting resonse as i mentioned in question